# Find a suitable algorithm to hash a filename/directory name

Tags: windows, algorithm, hash

I am thinking of developing something which could hash a file/directory name so that the size of path is reduced.

It is also desirable the number of collisions is minimized. Let us take an example where I want to hash a 85 char long string to a 8 char long hash.

eg. ".../thisIsSomeVerySuperUltraBigHugeVerySuperUltraBigHugeDirectoryName/..." => .../ebaca39c/...

But the problem with using a hash function is that when it outputs a 8 byte long character string, the string might contain characters like /:*?"<>| which windows does not allow to be used as directory names.

Is there any way I can get around this? Perhaps a hash function which only generated certain characters? Or, any other way?

Comment: What environment are you working on that you can't just store the filepath as a string? How many filepaths are you storing?

Is the size taken up by filepaths even a realistic concern?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a base64 representation of the bytes of any hash function (e.g. SHA1) and remove `/`,`+`, and `=` or replace them with some other character. And truncate to the length you want. Note that hashing different names might give you the same hash if you restrict yourself to a short name.

However, you can also just choose a random string instead of a hash. Take a look at [Path.GetRandomFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) .